# Auto restart MVC application after server crashes and restarts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have used Quartz schedule in my  MVC app which starts at application_start, I deployed the app on IIS, in case if the server crashes and then restarts, how to make my app run automatically, so that schedular start again automatically

This is first time that I deployed Quartz application on any server

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            JobScheduler.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server crashes then on the next http request your application will start again. Then your `JobSchedular` will resume again as if it is running for the first time. There is nothing to be done.

However, question is when the server crashes will your AppPool restart again or not. Server crash is not a normal scenario and should not be expected to happen. Not just crash scenarios but also AppPool recycles - the whole web application will start again on the next http request.

I suggest on the IIS AppPool settings set the `Idle Time-out Action` to *Suspend* instead of the default *Terminate*.

After the server resumes, if you do not want to wait till the next http request then you will have to hook an external trigger to initiate the app start. You can do that with a windows schedule job (which will hit a Url of your site) or 3rd party service to hit your site in a regular interval.

After a crash if the AppPool is down (stopped) then there is nothing you can do from your web application code.